# How to change PHP file webserver location

Tags: php

I have recently got myself into learning PHP. I have a mac and the php manual said php files should be placed in Library/WebServer/Documents in order for localhost to work with php files... Is there anyway I can change the working directory of php to somewhere else?

Thank you!

Comment: Just wondering... but, is there anything wrong with that folder path?  I've been using it for OS X servers for quite some time...  Alternatively, if you are looking for a way to "bookmark" that directory so you can get to it more easily (when editing PHP files, etc.) you could always try using symlinks (http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/creating-soft-link-or-symbolic-link/) to make things easier.  The webserver location would still be the same... but you'd be able to go to a certain "alias/shortcut" folder that takes you to the actual webserver location... when editing files.

Comment: No any specific way to change WD,,, it can be placed anywhere ,, but it should map the INI settings <Document Directory> here you can give thedirectory name that points to your web server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it, just make sure to change server.document-root value so it will point to the same location as doc_root in php.ini. For example, if you use apache make sure that  DocumentRoot defined in the apache configuration (httpd.conf) is pointing to the same folder as doc_root.